# VPN to an SBS server keeps asking for redial after a certain period of time, even if you are active

Tags: vpn, windows-sbs

I got provided a VPN connections to the Windows SBS server of a client.

The connection terminates after a while (about 60 minutes) even if it has been busy for a while.

I cannot seem to edit the VPN settings (it was part of an MSI file), so I wonder if there is a way:

- to make the delay longer before disconnecting,
- make it watch activity before disconnecting,
- make it not disconnect at all,
- or make it automatically redial.

I unpacked the MSI installer, it seems [CMAK](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Windows-Server-2008-Connection-Manager-Administration-Kit.html) based (all the files mentioned in that article extract from this MSI). The connection pased settings seem to be in a CMS file (INI file style). I could find the [documentation on the Windows 2003 CMS settings format](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc939869.aspx); any pointers to newer are welcome.

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of VPN software is it?  Have you spoken to the people who provided the client installer (they may be the ones who have to change it)?

Comment: @techie007 they are on holiday, but it seems a CMAK based setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are using CMAK then I assume they are using the standard Windows Routing and Remote Access Server (RRAS) to provide the VPN.

Since you say the time to disconnect is about the same each time, and that it seems to not be checking for the conenciton to be Idle, then perhaps check is ensure that there is no Session-Timeout value set on the RRAS itself.

[image: RRASSessionTimeout]

Comment: Thanks; any idea if I can have it reconnect from the client side automatically by modifying the CMS file?